# Assigning same value to the neighbours

Tags: matlab, neighbours

I'm trying to assign that value which is more repeated in an 8x8 neighbourhood to be the value of all the pixels in that neighbourhood.

I made a call to the following function:

```
   function ret = spatial_val(x)
       [m,n]=size(x);
       [a,b]=hist(x(:),unique(x));
       most_frequent_value=mode(x(:));
       for i=1:m
           for j=1:n
               x(i,j)=most_frequent_value;
               ret(i,j)=x(i,j);
           end
       end
   end
```

Using:

```
new_img = nlfilter(img, [8,8], @spatial_val);
```

But, I get the following error:

```
Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch.

Error in nlfilter (line 75)
        b(i,j) = feval(fun,x,params{:});

Error in Fuzzy_CMeans_ali (line 186)
    new_img = nlfilter(img, [8,8], @spatial_val);
```

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

you need your function to supply a single value not a matrix. It is also not clear what is the default incase you you have two or more numbers that appear the same amount of times most frequently. Ignoring this case for the time being,  you can simplify your function as follows:

```
function ret = spatial_val(x)    
   [a,b]=hist(x(:),unique(x));
   [c ret]=max(a)
```

the variable `ret` will now carry the value that is most repeated element in the nxm block that the filter picks.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you were trying to do is:

```
function ret = spatial_val(x)
    ret = ones(size(x))*mode(x(:));
end
```

### EDIT - 1

All you need may be in fact:

```
function ret = spatial_val(x)
    ret = uint8(mode(double(x(:))));
end
```

And then:

```
B = nlfilter(lena,[8 8],@spatial_val);
imshow(B);
```

### EDIT - 2

The code below will do exactly what you need.

**spatial_val.m**

```
function ret = spatial_val(x)
    ret = uint8(ones(size(x))*mode(double(x(:))));
end
```

**main.m**

```
clear;
close;
clc;

lena = imread('lena.jpg');

[m, n] = size(lena);
result = uint8(zeros([m, n]));

window_size = [8, 8];

for ii=1:window_size(1):m
    for jj=1:window_size(2):n
        result(ii:min(ii+window_size(1),m),jj:min(jj+window_size(2),n)) = spatial_val(lena(ii:min(ii+window_size(1),m),jj:min(jj+window_size(2),n)));
    end
end

subplot(1,2,1);
imshow(lena);
subplot(1,2,2);
imshow(result);
```

This gives:

[image]

Comment: I think you mean `ret = ones(size(x)) * mode(x(:));`

Comment: @Roney Michael. Thanks for your reply. So, does *ret = uint8(mode(double(x(:))));* give the `mode ` value for **all** the neighbourhood pixels?

Comment: It does not, sadly. It does the same operation for each pixel and its neighbourhood. I think this is the closest thing you can get via an inbuilt function, though it should be easy enough to write one on your own.

Answer (score 0):

From MatLab (R2011b) documentation:

> `B = nlfilter(A, [m n], fun)` applies the function fun to each m-by-n sliding block of the grayscale image `A`. `fun` is a function that accepts an m-by-n matrix as input and returns a **scalar** (!!!) result.

You function returns 8x8 matrix, not scalar.

Comment: But, I think the value will be applied to the `center` pixel, but takes into account the `neighbourhood` pixel. So, the result is a scalar?

Comment: Yes, the return value is calculated from mxn neighborhood and will be placed in center pixel of the result image (center pixel only for odd `m` and `n`). Roney solution shold do the job.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
im = imread('cameraman.tif');
imp = blockproc(im,[8 8],@(bs) mode(bs.data(:))*ones(size(bs.data),'like',bs.data));
imshow(imp)
```